# Nuxt SPA with Pre Rendered static content HTML

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt generate --spa` to build out my files into my dist folder. It is creating the actual .html files like products/product.html however it is still chunking the files in javascript script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/890d3a2acad1dc557c61.js"></script>
```

I also have my app set as 'spa' mode in nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
}
```

How can I set nuxt to generate the required html files and to acutally generate static .html code in the source code when you view the website in the browser?

Comment: isn't there a "_nuxt" folder inside the generated dist?